# npm command to uninstall or prune unused packages in Node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, uninstallation

Is there a way to simply uninstall all unused (undeclared) dependencies from a Node.js project (ones that are no longer defined in my `package.json`.) When I update my application I like to have the unreferenced packages removed automatically.

Comment: Unused by what? Do you mean to remove folders from `node_modules` when they're removed from the respective `package.json`?

Comment: exactly, mhm npm ll already gives a good hint which are the candidates.

Answer (score 802, accepted):

***Note**: Recent `npm` versions do this automatically when running `npm install` if package-locks are enabled, so this is not necessary except for removing development packages with the `--production` flag.*

---

Run [`npm prune`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prune) to remove modules not listed in `package.json`.

From `npm help prune`:

> This command removes "extraneous" packages.  If a package name is provided, then only packages matching one of the supplied names are removed.
>
> Extraneous packages are packages that are not listed on the parent package's dependencies list.
>
> If the `--production` flag is specified, this command will remove the packages specified in your devDependencies.

Comment: If I read that correctly, this would remove all sub-dependencies, since they're not listed in `package.json`. Is that right? So, the next update or install would have to reinstall them.

Comment: Yes, it will remove sub-dependencies. Sub-dependencies are actually stored inside the module's own `node_modules` directory, so they are removed with the module.

Comment: Let me give an example. I remove karma from my `package.json`, but leave bower. When I run `npm prune`, I expect all of karma, including its own `node_modules` folder containing its dependencies, to be removed. What about bower's dependencies (bower-json, bower-logger, chmodr, fstream, glob, et al.). Technically, those aren't listed in my project's `package.json`. Are those removed or not?

Comment: No, they are not. Note that they're *not* in your own `node_modules`, but *inside* `node_modules/bower/node_modules`, "protected" by `node_modules/bower/package.json`. Dependencies of your package and that of your package's dependencies *are not mixed*.

Comment: That was my assumption, but the documentation translates to "This command removes packages that are not listed on the parent package's dependencies list." It would seem to be incorrect, or misleading at best.

Comment: The documentation just does not takes into account sub-dependencies, as they are treated as part of their parent packages. I'll add a clarification to the answer later.

Comment: If you see an npm module remain in your `node_modules/` folder after running `npm prune` even though it's not in `package.json` - make sure to check your `npm-shrinkwrap.json`. If it's there, the only soluiton is to `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install` !

Comment: **and** delete your shrinkwrap before npm install, should have been in above instructions.

Comment: I use the `depcheck` package installed globally to check what packages are not being used. Then I go to the package-json and remove the unused packages. After those two steps, I run `npm prune` and everything ends right.

Comment: I replaced `uuid` with `uuidv4` in `package.json`, ran `npm install`, `npm prune`, noticed `uuid` still in `package-lock.json`, removed that, ran `npm prune`, saw it removed, ran `npm install`, and it returned to `package-lock.json` as it's a dependency of `uuidv4` i guess.

Comment: @Darkhogg _Recent npm versions do this automatically_ When doing what? Running `npm install`?

Comment: @NilsLindemann Yes, exactly. I've added a clarification in the post, thank you.

Comment: `npm install --production` is working exactly and it also removing unwanted and global packages along with dev dependencies.

Comment: Have no idea why 'npm prune' removes my typescript folder in node_modules ... So, just take my disk space npm.

Answer (score 387):

If you're not worried about a couple minutes time to do so, a solution would be to `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install` again to rebuild the local modules.

Comment: It would be nice if people stopped downvoting this without comment.. it's a valid strategy to resetting a node project dependencies as an alternative to the accepted answer. If you damaged a node_modules sub-directory contents (easy to do with sym-linked dependencies) or if you've had additional changes like node or npm version bumps prune will not properly cleanup the node_modules folder but this answer will.

Comment: Rebuilding `node_modules` also verifies the `package.json` file describes a reproducible dependency graph. Removing and re-installing your `node_modules` is basically a deploy test.

Comment: @joemaller Not necessarily, most deployment workflows have, either implicitly or explicitly, some kind of cache.  If a package is already installed and fits the specification, it's kept. Removing then reinstalling will bump that package(s) to the latest version that matches.

Comment: `npm prune` didn't help one iota, but this did. My problem was a broken symlink.

Comment: What about peer dependencies? I think the the objective is to remove all obsolete dependencies, but not removing the whole node_modules and re-installing all peer dependencies again.

Comment: Under many non-ideal circumstances that's currently infeasible with npm. Also the question definitely did not specify some constraint on repeated work or additional fetching, just how to achieve the end goal. This answer satisfies the question as stated, despite what others may want beyond that goal.

Comment: a handy one liner is `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` punch it in walk away come back. Life is good.

Comment: This answer is good enough for John Resig: https://twitter.com/jeresig/status/916729473814417408

Comment: @Anoop.P.A Downvoting (anonymously) is an intended and appreciated thing. https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote Voting without a good reason is not appreciated.

Comment: This is the best way. It is a better tested use-case for npm and anecdotally faster too. Other options (namely `npm prune`) can leave the modules in a weird state, causing hangs and failures down the line.

Answer (score 27):

### You can use **npm-prune** to remove extraneous packages.

```
npm prune [[<@scope>/]<pkg>...] [--production] [--dry-run] [--json]
```

This command removes "extraneous" packages. If a package name is provided, then only packages matching one of the supplied names are removed.

Extraneous packages are packages that are not listed on the parent package's dependencies list.

If the **--production** flag is specified or the **NODE_ENV** environment variable is set to **production**, this command will remove the packages specified in your **devDependencies**. Setting **--no-production** will negate **NODE_ENV** being set to **production**.

If the **--dry-run** flag is used then no changes will actually be made.

If the **--json** flag is used then the changes **npm prune** made (or would have made with **--dry-run**) are printed as a JSON object.

In normal operation with package-locks enabled, extraneous modules are pruned automatically when modules are installed and you'll only need this command with the **--production** flag.

If you've disabled package-locks then extraneous modules will not be removed and it's up to you to run **npm prune** from time-to-time to remove them.

### Use npm-dedupe to reduce duplication

```
npm dedupe
npm ddp
```

Searches the local package tree and attempts to simplify the overall structure by moving dependencies further up the tree, where they can be more effectively shared by multiple dependent packages.

For example, consider this dependency graph:

```
a
+-- b <-- depends on c@1.0.x
|    `-- c@1.0.3
`-- d <-- depends on c@~1.0.9
     `-- c@1.0.10
```

In this case, **npm-dedupe** will transform the tree to:

```
 a
 +-- b
 +-- d
 `-- c@1.0.10
```

Because of the hierarchical nature of node's module lookup, b and d will both get their dependency met by the single c package at the root level of the tree.

The deduplication algorithm walks the tree, moving each dependency as far up in the tree as possible, even if duplicates are not found. This will result in both a flat and deduplicated tree.

Comment: I have MORE items in my node_modules folder **after** running npm dedupe. Sigh!

Comment: does remove and uninstall mean the same thing when it comes to using prune? I ran a prune instance with a  `--production` flag.  But my package.json file never udpated.

Comment: prune removes those files that present in the node_modules folder but not listed as any package's dependency list. 
If the --production flag is specified or the NODE_ENV environment variable is set to production, this command will remove the packages specified in your devDependencies.

Answer (score 10):

You can run `npx depcheck` to get the list of dependencies and devDependencies that are not being used in the project.

Then you can run `npm uninstall pkg1 pkg2` and so on to remove the dependencies.

Or you can also remove the dependencies from **package.json** and reinstall the packages after deleting **node_modules** and **package-lock.json**