# Removing node_modules directory in my project

Tags: laravel

What is the right way of removing the entire node_modules directory. Do i have to delete it right away

Comment: Can you show your `package.json` file and indicate which ones you want removing? Also, have your used `npm` or `yarn` to install them?

Comment: Yes, I deleted my node_modules folder

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately you will need the modules for the application to work (if they are not development dependencies)...

If you want to erase modules you installed for development and not required in production then you can use [`npm prune`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417014/npm-command-to-uninstall-unused-packages-in-node-js).

Also, if you're using git you can add `/node_modules` to the `.gitignore` file, so you aren't saving libraries to your repo, and then later you can install dependencies by running `npm install`.

Comment: I"ve already deleted my node_modules in my project directory. Is it alright?

Comment: should be fine, just run `npm install` to get it back when nothing works :)

Comment: @upful Just a note that Node isn't strictly required for Laravel to work. It powers some optional stuff like the Vue integrations and Laravel Mix, but it's entirely possible to have a Laravel project with no Node modules.

Answer (score 1):

i lost count on how many times i deleted node_modules just by pressing delete button. Had no problem so far, as long as you don't forget to

```
npm install
```

everytime you delete node_modules to install dependency that is required by your app.

Answer (score 1):

Best way which i found,in root of app from cmd `rmdir /S node_modules` and thats it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `rm -rf /node_modules` to remove this from project