# How to list unused node modules/dependencies from your React Project?

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs, npm, node-modules

Need a solution to **remove unused node modules and node modules dependencies from a project**.

I have searched internet and found couple of NPM package to do something similar but not exactly my requirement.

**Please note**, Node modules should be listed/removed if that is neither a dependencies in other node modules nor used in any project code.

**Please help**

Comment: Are you using webpack?, if so, you can use tree shaking https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

Comment: we are not using webpack. Also treeshaking will not remove modules which are not used in my code.

Comment: This question is asked in a more general way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675725/find-unused-npm-packages-in-package-json).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run npm prune to unbuild modules not listed in package.json.

From npm help prune:

This command removes "extraneous" packages. If a package name is provided, then only packages matching one of the supplied names are removed.

Extraneous packages are packages that are not listed on the parent package's dependencies list.

If the --production flag is specified, this command will remove the packages specified in your devDependencies.

From : [npm command to uninstall unused packages in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417014/npm-command-to-uninstall-unused-packages-in-node-js)

Comment: This won't remove items that are unused within the actual codebase.

Comment: as @zero298 mentioned, provided solution with not remove Node modules from actual code base.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps you could use a tool like [`depcheck`](https://github.com/depcheck/depcheck):

> Depcheck is a tool for analyzing the dependencies in a project to see: how each dependency is used, which dependencies are useless, and which dependencies are missing from package.json.

Another one is [`npm-check`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check)

> Check for outdated, incorrect, and unused dependencies.
>   ... Kindly informs you if a dependency is not being used in your code ...

Comment: Tried npm-check, it uses a huge amount of my ram and swap and my pc freezes shortly after. depcheck seems to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently used [npm-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check#on-the-command-line)

> Check for outdated, incorrect, and unused dependencies.

After installing just run the command in terminal:

```
$ npm-check
```

[image: npm check result]

Comment: doesn't work correctly with react/remix set up. Gave me many unused packages and I'm 100% that they are used.