# How can i improve this function to delete old node_modules folders

Tags: python

The goal of this script is to delete all `node_modules` that haven't been touch in the last 15 days.

It is currently working, but as it goes inside each folder because of `os.walk` i lose efficiency as i don't have to go inside a `node_modules` folder because it's exactly what i want to delete

```py
import os
import time
import shutil

PATH = "/Users/wagnermattei/www"

now = time.time()
old = now - 1296000
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(PATH, topdown=False):
    for _dir in dirs:
        if _dir == 'node_modules' and os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(root, _dir)) < old:
            print('Deleting: '+os.path.join(root, _dir))
            shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(root, _dir))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Python 3, you can use `Path` from `pathlib` module with `rglob` function to find only `node_modules` directory. That way you will only iterate through `node_modules` directory in your `for` loop and excluding other files

```
import os
import time
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

PATH = "/Users/wagnermattei/www"
now = time.time()
old = now - 1296000

for path in Path(PATH).rglob('node_modules'):
    abs_path = str(path.absolute())
    if os.path.getmtime(abs_path) < old:
        print('Deleting: ' + abs_path)
        shutil.rmtree(abs_path)
```

Update: If you don't want to check `node_modules` directory if one of its parent directories is also a `node_modules` and is deleted. You can use `os.listdir` instead to non-recursively list all the directories in the current directory and use it with a recursive function so that you can traverse down the directory tree and will always check the parent directories first before checking their subdirectories. If the parent directory is an unused `node_modules`, you can delete that directory and don't traverse further down to the subdirectories

```
import os
import time
import shutil

PATH = "/Users/wagnermattei/www"
now = time.time()
old = now - 1296000

def traverse(path):
    dirs = os.listdir(path)
    for d in dirs:
        abs_path = os.path.join(path, d)
        if d == 'node_modules' and os.path.getmtime(abs_path) < old:
            print('Deleting: ' + abs_path)
            shutil.rmtree(abs_path)
        else:
            traverse(abs_path)

traverse(PATH)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is, i don't want to go in folders like: `my-project/node_modules/a-lib/node_modules` because the first `node_modules` will be deleted anyway

Comment: @WagnerMattei Ok I've updated my answer so that if the first `node_modules` in `my-project/node_modules/a-lib/node_modules` is deleted, it won't look for the second `node_modules` inside it

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions are more effective in python that for loops. But I'm not sure if it's better for debugging.

You should try this:

```
[shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(root, _dir) \
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(PATH, topdown=False) \
    for _dir in dirs \
        if _dir == 'node_modules' and os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(root, _dir)) < old ]
```

But I think you should use npm to manage the old packages. Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417014/npm-command-to-uninstall-or-prune-unused-packages-in-node-js) can help :)

Comment: Hey, yeah the post is awesome, but i'm not looking to delete unused packages, i want to delete all of them, even if declared on package.json, my only rule is that it is on a projetct that i have not work in the last 15 days

Comment: Oh okok, I hope the list comprehension helps you. The performance will increase but I'm not sure how much. 